# Invalid hook call error in React Material-UI simplest Hello Wold test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I want to start a project with `React` and `Material-UI`. First, I wanted to do simplest Hello World. simplest based on official documentation in a fresh `Ubuntu` OS, but I get error! my code is this:

## App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SMSAuth from './components/SMSAuth';

function App() {
  return (
     <SMSAuth/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## SMSAuth.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function SMSAuth(){
    return(
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
            Hello World
        </Button>
    );
}

export default SMSAuth
```

I use Material-UI's official documentation. But I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code using hooks. Are you sure the error doesn't originate in a different component? Or as the error says, you might have multiple versions of React, like material-ui might be using one and your app is using another.

Comment: If you do an `npm ls react` that should help you determine if you've got two versions of it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see materialize in your dependencies try re-installing with `npm install @material-ui/core` in the root directory of your app.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

You must include the library.